# How to show this equality of $\rho(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let I have $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space, then $X,Y \in \Sigma$. Define $\rho (X,Y)$ by $\rho (X,Y)$ = correlation between random variable $I_X$ and $I_Y$, where $I_X$ and $I_Y$ are the indicator function of $X$ and $Y$. Express $\rho (X,Y)$ in term of $\mu (X)$, $\mu (Y)$, $\mu(XY)$. Conclude that $\rho(X,Y)=0$, if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

> How to show that: $$\rho(X,Y)= \frac{\mu(XY)\,\mu(X^cY^c)-\mu(XY^c)\,\mu(X^cY)}{(\mu(X) \,\mu(X^c)-\mu(Y) \,\mu(Y^c))^{1/2}};0<\mu(X)<1;\,0<\mu(Y)<1$$

Comment: This was discussed in-depth yesterday in [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), including my pointing out that the denominator has an erroneous minus sign, but the question seems to have been deleted there.

Comment: Please do **not** vandalise your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer for the quote, but definition we have
$$\rho(X,Y) = \frac{\operatorname{var}(I_X,I_Y)}{\sigma_{I_X}\sigma_{I_Y}} = \frac{\mathbb{E}(I_XI_Y)-\mathbb{E}(I_X)\mathbb{E}(I_Y)}{\sqrt{\left(\mathbb{E}(I_X^2)-\mathbb{E}(I_X)^2\right)\left(\mathbb{E}(I_Y^2)-\mathbb{E}(I_Y)^2\right)}}=\\
= \frac{\mathbb{E}(I_{X\cap Y})-\mathbb{E}(I_X)\mathbb{E}(I_Y)}{\sqrt{\left(\mathbb{E}(I_X)-\mathbb{E}(I_X)^2\right)\left(\mathbb{E}(I_Y)-\mathbb{E}(I_Y)^2\right)}} = 
\frac{\mu(X\cap Y)-\mu(X)\mu(Y)}{\sqrt{\left(\mu(X)-\mu(X)^2\right)\left(\mu(Y)-\mu(Y)^2\right)}}$$
and clearly $\rho(X,Y)=0$ iff $\mu(X\cap Y)=\mu(X)\mu(Y)$.

Comment: For things more complicated than two simple events, zero correlation does *not* imply independence

Comment: why the denaminator above in third form there is no "square" $E(I_X)$ $$\frac{\mathbb{E}(I_{X\cap Y})-\mathbb{E}(I_X)\mathbb{E}(I_Y)}{\sqrt{\left(\mathbb{E}(I_X)-\mathbb{E}(I_X)^2\right)\left(\mathbb{E}(I_Y)-\mathbb{E}(I_Y)^2\right)}}$$

Comment: @lpchristine, I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

To finish @JonathanY 's answer: $$(1)\quad \mu(XY^c)=\mu(X)-\mu(XY).$$
$$(2)\quad \mu(X^c Y)=\mu(Y)-\mu(XY).$$
$$(3)\quad\mu(X^c Y^c)=\mu(Y^c)-\mu(XY^c)=1-\mu(Y)-\mu(XY^c)=1-\mu(Y)-\mu(X)+\mu(XY),$$
using (1). Now, putting these together,
\begin{align*}
&\,\mu(XY)\mu(X^c Y^c)-\mu(XY^c)\mu(X^cY)\\
=&\,\mu(XY)\left(1-\mu(Y)-\mu(X)+\mu(XY)\right)-\left(\mu(X)-\mu(XY)\right)\left(\mu(Y)-\mu(XY)\right)\\
=&\,\mu(XY)-\mu(XY)\mu(Y)-\mu(XY)\mu(X)+\mu(XY)^2-\mu(X)\mu(Y)+\mu(X)\mu(XY)+\mu(Y)\mu(XY)-\mu(XY)^2\\
=&\,\mu(XY)-\mu(X)\mu(Y).\quad\blacksquare
\end{align*}

Comment: You may also need to say $\mu(X)-\mu(X)^2=\mu(X)(\mu(X)+\mu(X^c))-\mu(X)^2=\mu(X)\mu(X^c)$ and similarly for $Y$